# Dilogarithm: real and complex

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I am working with the dilogarithm defined as

$$
Li_2(z) = -\int_0^1 ln(1 - zt)\frac{dt}{t}
\tag1$$

which is valid for $z\in\mathbb{C}$, while $t\in\mathbb{R}$

In this [link](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?bibcode=1995CeMDA..62...93O&db_key=AST&page_ind=0&plate_select=NO&data_type=GIF&type=SCREEN_GIF&classic=YES) , it is provided a paper where Eq. (1) is splitted into its real and imaginary parts as

$$
Li_2(z) = -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 ln(1 - 2tr\cos\phi + (tr)^2)\frac{dt}{t} + i\int_0^1 \arctan\left(\frac{tr\sin\phi}{1 - tr\cos\phi}\right)\frac{dt}{t}, \quad z = re^{i\phi}\in\mathbb{C},\ r\in\mathbb{R},\ \phi\in[0, 2\pi)
\tag2$$

My question is: if Eq. (1) is valid in $\mathbb{R}$ for being defined in general for $\mathbb{C}$, then for $\phi = 0$ Eq. (2) should be reduced to Eq. (1) with $z = r$, but what ou really get is

$$
Li_2(z = r) = -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 ln(1 - tr(2 -tr))\frac{dt}{t}, \quad r\in\mathbb{R}
$$

Isn't this a contradiction? Is maybe Eq. (2) wrong?

Comment: (1) and (2) can not coincide everywhere. The imaginary part of $\ln(1 - (x + i y) t)$ is
$$\arg(1 - (x + i y) t) =
\arctan(1 - x t, -y t) \neq
-\arctan \frac {y t} {1 - x t}$$
(as the range of one-argument $\arctan$ has width $\pi$, not $2 \pi$). If we choose the principal value of the argument (not $\phi \in [0, 2 \pi)$) and (2) is used to evaluate the polylogarithm inside the unit circle, there is no issue because $\arctan(u, v) = \arctan(v/u)$ for $u > 0$. If $\operatorname {Re} z > 1$, (2) will not coincide with (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you get your result.  (You don't show your work.)  Expanding the original integrand, using $\Re(z)$ for the real part of $z$ and $\Im(z)$ for the imaginary part,
\begin{align*}
R &= \Re(\ln(1-z t))  \\
    &= \frac{1}{2}\ln( 1 - 2t \Re(z) + t^2 \Re(z)^2 + t^2 \Im(x)^2 )  \text{.}
\end{align*}

If $z$ is real, $\Im(z) = 0$ and $\Re(z) = z$.  So,
\begin{align*}
R &= \frac{1}{2}\ln( 1 - 2t z + t^2 z^2  )  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Similarly, if $z$ is nonnegative real and $r \geq 0$, $\phi = 0$ and if $z$ is nonpositive real and $r \leq 0$, $\phi = 0$.  Either way, we get your $\phi = 0$, so $\cos \phi = 1$ and also $z = r$.  Therefore,
\begin{align*}
R &= \frac{1}{2}\ln( 1 - 2t r\cos \phi + (t r)^2  )  
\end{align*}
and we find the real part integrand in eqn. (2) is what is expected form the integrand in eqn. (1) under the assumptions $r = z$ and $\phi = 0$.

Comment: From the beginning, I provided a link with paper that contains Eq. (2) so I don't know why you say I don't show my work

Comment: @Vicky : "but what ou really get is" [equation out of nowhere, with no work shown].

Comment: The last equation was obtained by taking $\phi = 0$ in Eq. (2), that's why I was asking about contradictions. Shouldn't I get $-\int_0^1 ln(1 - tr)dt/t$ in case of $\phi = 0$ so we just have Eq. (1) but with $z = r$?

Comment: @Vicky : $\frac{1}{2} \ln( 1 - 2 tr + (tr)^2) = \frac{1}{2} \ln ( (1-tr)^2) = \ln(1-tr)$.

Comment: Your last expression is only valid if $tr < 1$ but the paper says that Eq. (1) is valid outside the unit circle, so how do you prove it when $r > 1$?

Comment: @Vicky : You are conflating the [real logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) with the [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm).  Since eqn (1) permits complex $z$, we must be using the complex logarithm.  Then the only difficulty is  when $tr = 1$, the one case that cannot be reached with *your* specialization $\phi = 0$.  Use $\phi = \pi$ and $r = -z$.