# Dilogarithm of a negative real number outside unit circle

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, analytic-functions, polylogarithm

The dilogarithm is defined in $\mathbb{C}$ as

$$
Li_2(z) = -\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1 - zt)}{t} dt
$$

Because $1-zt \in \mathbb{C}$, then you can write $\ln(1 - zt) = \ln|1 - zt| + i·\arg(1 - zt)$

As pointed out by @Maxim in [Dilogarithm: real and complex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668948/dilogarithm-real-and-complex) you can pick the principal determination of the argument $\arg$, which is the angle in $(-\pi, \pi]$ so

$\arg(1 - zt) = \begin{cases}2\arctan\left(\frac{\Im[1 - zt]}{|1 - zt| + \Re[1 - zt]}\right),\ \mbox{if $\Im \neq 0$ or $\Re > 0$}\\ \pi,\ \mbox{if $\Im = 0$ and $\Re < 0$}\\\mbox{undefined}, \ \mbox{if $\Re = 0$ and $\Im = 0$} \end{cases}$

and therefore

$$
Li_2(z) = -\int_0^1 \frac{\ln|1 - zt|}{t}dt - i\int_0^1 2\arctan\left(\frac{\Im[1 - zt]}{|1 - zt| + \Re[1 - zt]}\right)\frac{dt}{t}, \quad \mbox{for $z \in \mathbb{C} - (1, +\infty)$}
\tag1$$

I want to pay attention to the special case $z\in(1, +\infty)$. For this one,  $1 - zt < 0$ when $t>1/z$, so for this interval the complex logarithm is not defined within the principal **analytic** determination, i.e, $\arg \in (-\pi, \pi)$, that's why we can take just the principal determination as before. Then we can write the complex logarithm for this case as $\ln(1 - zt) = \ln|1 - zt| + i\pi$, so the dilogarithm is now

$$
Li_2(z) = -\int_0^1 \frac{\ln|1 - zt|}{t}dt - i\pi\int_{1/z}^1\frac{dt}{t} = -\int_0^1 \frac{\ln|1 - zt|}{t}dt - i\pi\ln(|z|), \quad \mbox{for $z\in(1, +\infty)$}\tag2
$$

According to Mathematica/Wolfram-Alpha website, $\Im[Li_2(r)] = -\pi\ln(r)$, where $r\in(1, +\infty)$. You can see that [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-pi*ln%28%7Cx%7C%29+%3D+imaginary%28polylog%5B2%2C+%7Cx%7C%5D%29+from+x+%3D+1+to+15), take a look to the plot.

Hence, it seems I'm right but is it really good to allow $\arg$ to be equal to $\pi$ even if this breaks the analyticity of the complex logarithm? The definition of $\arg$ is independent of the logarithm, but when you use it within the logarithm, it make me wonder if it's a good thing to do or maybe we should never take into account the region $z\in(1, +\infty)$. To what extend is analyticity something to worry about?

Comment: No, I was pointing out that we *can not* have $\arg(1 - (x + i y) t) = -\arctan(y t/(1 - x t))$ for all $x + i y \in \mathbb C \setminus [1, \infty)$ and all $t \in (0, 1)$.

Comment: @Maxim Then, how do we compute the imaginary part? I'm getting so confused

Comment: @Maxim I've made an edit, maybe (1) and (2) are ok now?

Comment: That's an ingenious way to write $\arg$ in terms of one-argument $\arctan$, but I'm not sure what it achieves. If we evaluate the integral of $-\ln(1 - z t)/t$ with the principal value of the logarithm, we get a branch of $\operatorname {Li}_2(z)$ which is analytic on $\mathbb C \setminus [1, \infty)$. We can also ask what the integral gives for $z \geq 1$ and define $\operatorname {Li}_2(z)$ to be equal to the integral for those values of $z$ as well, then that branch will be continuous at $1$ and continuous from below on $(1, \infty)$.

Comment: @Maxim it achieves a simple way to be numerically computed